# VBA Writing IFERROR to Multiple Cells with For...Next Loop

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to apply "=IFERROR" to a spreadsheet containing over 1000 rows of data. I already came up with a way to make the entries hard-coded. But is there a way to fill the cells with something like "=IFERROR(IFERROR(A1,B1),"")" rather than the value? Below is the hard-coded version:

```
Sub HardCodeIFERROR()             
    Dim a As Integer, xRecordCount1 As Integer
    Set w(1) = Sheets("ABC")
    xRecordCount1 = w(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For a = 1 To xRecordCount1

        w(1).Cells(a, 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Range("A" & a), Range("B" & a)), "")

        Next a
    Exit Sub


End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instead just use `.Formula`:

`w(1).Cells(a, 3).Formula = "=IFERROR(IFERROR(A" & a & ",B" & a & "),"""")"`

Note you can skip the loop and just use a range:

```
Sub HardCodeIFERROR()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim a As Integer, xRecordCount1 As Integer
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
xRecordCount1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With ws1
    .Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(xRecordCount1, 3)).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IFERROR(RC[-2],RC[-1]),"""")"
End With

End Sub
```

Note: Make sure to use the sheet with the `Rows.Count` whenever you use it, just like you do with `Cells()` and `Range()`.  Also, I changed the sheet name because I wasn't sure if you intended to do a Sheet Array or not, so I used a more clear (IMO) variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `Formula` property:

```
Sub HardCodeIFERROR()             
    Dim a As Integer, xRecordCount1 As Integer
    'Need to declare the size of the array if you are going to assign worksheets to "w(1)"
    Dim w(1 To 1) As Worksheet
    Set w(1) = Sheets("ABC")
    'Ensure you fully qualify "Rows.Count" by specifying which worksheet you are referring to
    xRecordCount1 = w(1).Cells(w(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    'Apply formula to all cells
    w(1).Range("C1:C" & xRecordCount1).Formula = "=IFERROR(IFERROR(S1,V1),"""")"
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice, I had the same idea in using a range instead of looping.  Just curious if you think doing the `w(1)` as the variable is a good idea? It may very well be, but I haven't seen arrays really used with worksheet names so am just curious.

Comment: @BruceWayne - I can see uses for using an "array of worksheets" (e.g. one worksheet for each month, accessed by the month number?), and I think I have actually done it myself once or twice in the past, but it's not something I would recommend the use of to someone who wasn't already using it.  I'm not sure why the OP was using it but, apart from the declaration (maybe it was a global variable?), they were using it consistently and correctly so I didn't want to change their code for no real reason.

Comment: @BruceWayne http://stackoverflow.com/a/43750702/6535336 (an array seemed the easiest thing to use)