# How do I refer to worksheets to loop through different worksheets and perform the same function on each of them?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and am trying to learn it. I've written this function to try to loop through some worksheets within the same workbook and add a column to update the week notated as 'ww' based on the cell to the left.

I'm having issues with the For loop where it's supposed to loop through the defined sh1 to sh3. How do I declare the sheets to loop if using sheet.("sh"&i) does not work for the For loop?

The `Sheets("sh" & i).Activate` part is where I receive the debug error.
"Run time error: 9
subscript out of range"

I'm largely unsure of what I'm doing and experimenting a lot. On the side not, is there any good online learning courses that I can use to grow my knowledge on VBA?

```
Function updateWWColumn()

    Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data_WE")
    Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data_E")
    Set sh3 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data_PC")

    'placeholder to contain the week number in integer form from the cell on the right.
    Dim placeholder As Integer
    Dim i As Integer    

    For i = 1 To 3
        Sheets("sh" & i).Activate ' Run time error: 9 subscript out of range
        ActiveSheet.Columns("U:U").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Worksheets("sh" & i).Columns("P:P").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        placeholder = Right(Worksheets("sh" & i).Range("S83"), 2)
        Worksheets("sh" & i).Range("T83").Value = "WW" & placeholder + 1
    Next i

End Function
```

Comment: You can step through the Sheets collection using numbers: Sheets(1), Sheets(2), etc. The number can be in a variable. Also, you can find the number of sheets using Sheets.Count. So you can use a For...Next loop like this: For i = 1 to Sheets.Count: set ws = Sheets(i): next i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use three variables to store your sheet references - use an array of three items that store your specific sheets.

So all I have done here is change sh1, sh2 and sh3 into an array called sh. Then wherever you would use`WorkSheets("sh"&i)` you can just use `sh(i)`

```
Function updateWWColumn()
    Dim sh(3) As Worksheet
    Set sh(1) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data_WE")
    Set sh(2) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data_E")
    Set sh(3) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data_PC")
    'placeholder to contain the week number in integer form from the cell on the right.
    Dim placeholder As Interger
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 3
        sh(i).Activate
        ActiveSheet.Columns("U:U"). _
        Insert Shift:=xlToRight, _
        CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

        sh(i).Columns("P:P"). _
        Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

        placeholder = Right(sh(i).Range("S83"), 2)
        sh(i).Range("T83").Value = "WW" & placeholder + 1
    Next i
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use an array of worksheets:

```
Public sh(1 To 3) As Worksheet

Sub updateWWColumn()  ' Only use Function when you are returning a value

    Set sh(1) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_WE")
    Set sh(2) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_E")
    Set sh(3) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data_PC")
    'placeholder to contain the week number in integer form from the cell on the right.
    Dim placeholder As Integer ' Note: Integer, not Interger
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To 3
        With sh(i)
            .Columns("U:U"). _
                Insert Shift:=xlToRight, _
                CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

            .Columns("P:P"). _
                Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

            placeholder = Right(.Range("S83"), 2)
            .Range("T83").Value = "WW" & placeholder + 1
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

---

Alternatively, you could loop through each worksheet using its name:

```
Sub updateWWColumn()  ' Only use Function when you are returning a value
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'placeholder to contain the week number in integer form from the cell on the right.
    Dim placeholder As Integer ' Note: Integer, not Interger
    Dim i As Integer

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("Data_WE", "Data_E", "Data_PC"))
        With ws
            .Columns("U:U"). _
                Insert Shift:=xlToRight, _
                CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

            .Columns("P:P"). _
                Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

            placeholder = Right(.Range("S83"), 2)
            .Range("T83").Value = "WW" & placeholder + 1
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I like the second solution you posted - using an array like that is a little cleaner than using three+ `Or Worksheet.Name = "Data_XX` statements or the like

Answer (score 0):

The other posted answers are good.  Alternatively, you can loop through every sheet in your workbook:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sht.Activate
    ' etc...
Next sht
```

Or, if you only want to affect sheets which start with the name `Data_`, you can embed an if statement:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Left(sht.Name, 5) = "Data_" Then
        sht.Activate
        ' etc...
    End If
Next sht
```